# retrieve fb userid in iOS Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

with the new changes in the FB API, I am at a loss.
I have an app that uses the FB login for the user, but I do not know how to obtain the userid after login to populate the in-app profile.

The userid would end up being used to initiate an fb-messenger chat.

The new update did away with the ability to retrieve userid, or did I miss a vital step here?

Answer (score 0):

I used this for my app and it still works

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logOut];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Process error %@",[error localizedDescription]);
            [indicator setHidden:YES];
            [Helper showToast:[error localizedDescription] withDuration:1];
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            [indicator setHidden:YES];
            [Helper showToast:@"You cancelled FB login" withDuration:1];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Logged in");
            [FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:TRUE];
            if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] tokenString]) {
                [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
                 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                     if (!error) {
                         DDLogDebug(@"%@",result);
                         DDLogDebug(@"token string = %@",[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString);
                         DDLogDebug(@"user id = %@",[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].userID);
```